# Which platform should i choose for scientific computing?

Tags: gpu, scientific-computing, playstation3

What are the pros and cons in choosing PS3 as a platform for scientific computing in detriment of GPU's?  Is It the better choice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no broad "better" choice, it is all dependent on the situation and what you're doing. Probably the biggest PRO to a PS3 is they're cheap by comparison. A computer can more easily scale bigger though (for a price) when looking into things like CUDA.

Comment: They don't have much ram, and how much heat do they generate ? Are they optimized to make good use of every cubic inch ? :D

Answer (score 2):

Stick with a PC, you will have a far easier life at the end of the day. I also wouldn't be surprised if you get more horsepower out of GPU's.

p.s., from what I know dispatching work to the cells is not an enjoyable task :D

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for GPU, for three reasons:

(a) GPU code can be developed, tested, and run on pretty much any PC you may want to use, with the only dependency being a $150 video card, whereas CELL/PS3 is a much more custom development environment and won't run natively on your laptop, etc.;

(b) I'm willing to bet a lot that GPUs and Cuda will be alive and well in 5 years, but I wouldn't put money on PS3 being around that long -- what are you going to do if PS4 has a totally different architecture and CELL effectively dies?

(c) There's a more vibrant research and development community around GPU than there is around PS3/Cell (outside of strict game development), so you're likely to be in more good company, have example code and tools to work with, etc.

Answer (score 1):

CUDA is pretty slick. I was shown a presentation recently demonstrating how easy it is to get at the power of the GPU's many cores using a C++ based syntax. If I was starting a parallel computing project now, I would probably take the PC/GPU-based route.

Answer (score 1):

A major objection to the PS3 (which is already quite a wacky choice unless you're under some pretty extreme price/performance constraints) has to be that Sony are [dropping support](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/ps3-drop-other-operating-systems) for installation of other OS.  In future, PS3s without the disabling firmware update may become harder and harder to get hold of.